# How to initiate multidimensional arraylist with different objects?

Tags: java

I'm having trouble trying to initiate an arraylist in which the first column I want to be a string, and the second column be a custom object.

For example `column [0]` be `String`, and `column[1]` be an `Integer`. Convention attempts of creating a multidimensional arraylist as in those used by `int[][]` or `String[][]` don't seem to work :( I would welcome any help. At this point I don't think it's something java allows. I can make it work for just one type of object but it's not what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using a `Map`?

Comment: an int[][] is not an ArrayList, it is just an array.  Don't confuse the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it does, but you weaken/eliminate type-checking:

```
Map myMap<String>, Integer> myData = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Now your list of strings can be retrieved by `myMap.keySet()` and values can be retrieved by `myMap.values()`. Each of these return a [Set](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), which you can easily convert to a [List](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) using the following code:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>(myMap.keySet()); // get your strings
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(myMap.values(); // get your numbers
```

Good luck and if you should run into problems, do leave a comment.

Comment: I've been looking into this constructor, however, it doesn't use the same methods that arraylists uses and so I'm detered a bit. Does it use the same methods as those in lists, arraylists? etc etc

Comment: I wish I could vote up but it doesn't let me. I would ask that all other viewers of this discussion vote up for you on my behalf :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you need an arraylist? You could create a `Map<String, Object>` or `Map<String, Integer>` or whatever you need..

Comment: I've actually been looking into this constructor though I've never used it

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are geared towards one specific type of *thing* - be they `Object` or `String` or `int`.   Despite the fact that you're adding multiple dimensions to them, they still only hold one type of information.

What you would rather have is a [mapping](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) between two objects.  This allows you to do the following:

- Associate any key to a particular value
- Eliminate duplicate key entries
- Be *much* easier to access instead of array indexing

Here's an example.  Say your custom object is a `Cat`, and you want to map the name of the owner to a particular `Cat`.   You create a new instance of a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

```
Map<String, Cat> catOwners = new HashMap<>();
```

You can then put elements into it...

```
catOwners.put("Jamie", new Cat("Tycho"));
```

...and retrieve them with relative ease.

```
Cat currentCat = catOwners.get("Jamie"); // gets Jamie's cat
```

if you *really* want to, you can even iterate over them using the [`Map.Entry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) object provided with all `Map`s:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Cat> element : catOwners.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(element.getKey()
        + " owns " + element.getValue().getName());
}
```

Comment: This is good but does Map act as an arraylist in which it can inherit methods from arraylist?

Comment: What methods do you require from a List?  The only few that I could think of are adding, finding, removing and iterating - and a `Map` is perfectly capable of doing all of that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Makoto, I'm experimenting with Map as we speak and this is helping.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the generic `Object` type, and cast accordingly.